# Finding the maximum, miniumum and nearest data in the Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the pandas data frame like below :

```
    A   B   C   D   E
  2014  132 463 52  463 413
  2015  31  71  237 71  149
  2016  64  138 305 138 21
  2017  33  338 338 338 177
  2018  20  413 413 413 187
  2019  237 149 149 149 214
  2020  209 21  21  21  456
  2021  4   177 177 71  52
  2022  169 187 187 138 237
  2023  400 214 214 338 214
  2024  300 456 463 52  456
```

I would like to find out which of these columns represent the maximum, minimum and nearest based on my average value (for example 100).Could you please suggest me the way to handle this issue effectively.

For Maximum and Minimum, I have tried like this :

```
  x = df-100
  rr=x.rank(axis=1)
  rrr=rr.sum()
```

Based on this I can find out which column represent maximum and minimum. Now, I would like to find out the nearest column. How can i do that. Please suggest whether my approach of finding maximum or minimum also making sense or not ?

Comment: What do you mean by nearest? Nearest sum or least square errors?

Comment: I mean the nearest sum

Comment: Take a look to `argmin` and `argmax` for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you think minimal `sum` of absolute values, you can use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) with [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.min.html):

```
print (df- 100).abs().sum()
A    1195
B    1743
C    1710
D    1462
E    1730
dtype: int64

print (df- 100).abs().sum().min()
1195

print (df- 100).abs().sum().isin([(df- 100).abs().sum().min()])
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
E    False
dtype: bool

print df.loc[:, (df- 100).abs().sum().isin([(df- 100).abs().sum().min()])]
        A
2014  132
2015   31
2016   64
2017   33
2018   20
2019  237
2020  209
2021    4
2022  169
2023  400
2024  300
```

EDIT:

You can get minimal, maximal and nearest value' s column by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) and [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df-100).sum()
A     499
B    1527
C    1456
D    1092
E    1476
dtype: int64
```

```
print (df-100).sum().idxmin()
A

print df.loc[:, (df-100).sum().idxmin()]
2014    132
2015     31
2016     64
2017     33
2018     20
2019    237
2020    209
2021      4
2022    169
2023    400
2024    300
Name: A, dtype: int64

print (df-100).sum().idxmax()
B

print df.loc[:, (df-100).sum().idxmax()]
2014    463
2015     71
2016    138
2017    338
2018    413
2019    149
2020     21
2021    177
2022    187
2023    214
2024    456
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

```
print (df-100).abs().sum().idxmin()
A

print df.loc[:, (df-100).abs().sum().idxmin()]
2014    132
2015     31
2016     64
2017     33
2018     20
2019    237
2020    209
2021      4
2022    169
2023    400
2024    300
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could use [`argmin`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwihx4yAgNbKAhWHjSwKHS6VDUoQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.Series.argmin.html&usg=AFQjCNEA59UnDdD8p6-IQoX6mKTBAsC-wQ&bvm=bv.113034660,d.bGg) for your sum of columns and then pass it to the `loc` for `df`:

```
In [120]: (df-100).abs().sum().argmin()
Out[120]: 'A'

In [121]: df.loc[:,(df-100).abs().sum().argmin()]
Out[121]:
2014    132
2015     31
2016     64
2017     33
2018     20
2019    237
2020    209
2021      4
2022    169
2023    400
2024    300
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

IIUC from your comment you need to find minimum negative value of the minumum column and maximum positive value of the maximum column. You could do that with:

```
In [147]: (df.loc[:,(df-100).abs().sum().argmin()] - 100).min()
Out[147]: -96

In [148]: (df.loc[:,(df-100).abs().sum().argmax()] - 100).max()
Out[148]: 363
```

**EDIT2**

Still hard to understand :). Maybe that?

```
col_min = df.loc[:,(df-100).abs().sum().argmin()] - 100
col_max = df.loc[:,(df-100).abs().sum().argmax()] - 100

In [13]: col_min
Out[13]: 
2014     32
2015    -69
2016    -36
2017    -67
2018    -80
2019    137
2020    109
2021    -96
2022     69
2023    300
2024    200
Name: A, dtype: int64

In [14]: col_max
Out[14]: 
2014    363
2015    -29
2016     38
2017    238
2018    313
2019     49
2020    -79
2021     77
2022     87
2023    114
2024    356
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . I have one concern about your solution. For maximum, I have to find the out the maximum value which are only positive and for minimum, I have to find out the minimum value which are negative only.

Comment: Thanks @Anton. In my case difference can be negative also, so I would like to find out the positive maximum value and negative minimum value of maximum and positive.

Comment: Thanks again @ Anton. My apologies if my question was not that clear.I will try to explain it further. What I am expecting is little bit different than you explained. I have calculated the difference between my data frame and avg. The difference can be both positive and negative. Now my concern is if I take the absolute i may not know that which values are less than the average one. So I would like to find the column which represent extreme two cases (Maximum and Minimum).

Comment: Are maximum and minumum values should be in one column or you need to get one column which contain maximum value and one with negative?

Comment: @ Anton Yes you are right, i need one column which contains maximum and other column with negative

Comment: @PUJA another attempt